# SQL Server connection problem via using sequalize with encryptset to true

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js, tedious

I have been working on a NodeJS project locally on my (Windows) machine which connects to a SQL server database using Sequelize. It works fine on my local machine but when I upload it to an Azure Web App I get the following error on each request..

Failed to connect to x.x.x.x:1433 - socket hang up (IP address replaced with X's by me)

The code is identical and I have checked there are no IP restrictions on the database, it's totally open. I have also checked that the environment variables (username/password etc.) are identical and being loaded correctly in production. In fact, my logging shows that the connection attempt is identical.

The only thing that makes it work is removing the Sequelize/tedious option {encrypt:true}.

So, just to be clear, encrypted connections work from localhost but not from an azure web app.

I have literally no idea why this could be so any suggestions would be helpful, even if they just point me in the right direction.

Here is my sequelize setup. Obviously I've redacted the host IP address and login details but they are the same from dev and production at the moment.

```
{

    'production': {
        'username': xxx,
        'password': xxx,
        'database': xxx,
        'host': xxx,
        'dialect': 'mssql',
        'dialectOptions': {
            'options': {
                'encrypt': true,
                'multipleStatements': true,
                'validateBulkLoadParameters': false
            }
        },
        'omitNull': true,
        'pool': {
            'max': 100,
            'min': 0,
            'acquire': 30000,
            'idle': 10000
        },
        'logging': false
    },

    'development': {
        'username': xxx,
        'password': xxx,
        'database': xxx,
        'host': xxx,
        'dialect': 'mssql',
        'dialectOptions': {
            'options': {
                'encrypt': true,
                'multipleStatements': true,
                'validateBulkLoadParameters': false,
                'debug': {
                    'packet': true,
                    'data': true,
                    'payload': true,
                    'token': true
                }
            }
        },
        'omitNull': true,
        'pool': {
            'max': 100,
            'min': 0,
            'acquire': 30000,
            'idle': 10000
        },
        'logging': false
    }

}
```

Comment: If removing `encrypt:true` makes it work then two possibilities come to mind: 1) there is no agreement for TLS protocol versions 1.0, 1.1, 1.2 between the client and server preventing a secure connection from being established, or 2) the host name in your config isn't mentioned in the Subject or DnsNames properties of the server's certificate so the client isn't trusting it. You could probably test for 2 by using both `encrypt: true` and `trustServerCertificate: true` in the options, or maybe use `openssl s_client` to dump the server's certificate and check its properties manually.

Comment: I will try (2), the host is an ip address. Would that fit with it working fine from my PC?

Comment: I tried adding trustServerCertificate: true but it still gave me the same error. Not sure I really understand (1), or why it would work on my local PC. I looked up "openssl s_client" but it seems like it would involve installing software on the server which I can't do becuase it's an azure web app.

Comment: How safe is it to just leave secure: false? I'm not sure what kind of attack would be possible? Sniffing the traffic between an Azure web app and an Azure VM?

Comment: If the same server IP address is used from Azure as is used on your machine then probably the server's certificate has been added to your own Trusted Certificates store.

Comment: OpenSSL can be installed on any computer that can access the target server. If you have remote access to the target server you can also go into SQL Server Configuration Manager and check the SQL Server's network configuration to see which SSL/TLS certificate it is configured to use, then look in Manage Computer Certificates (i.e.: certmgr.msc for Local Machine) > Personal > Certificates for the matching certificate and check its properties.

Comment: Only you can evaluate the merits of removing `encrypt: true` to make it work. If you have any kind of sensitive data going over the wire (e.g.: passwords or any other PII) it wouldn't seem like a good idea.